# Wordpress API criteria

Tags: php

I am installing paypal on a wordpress website. The built in API is asking for the following criteria:

- (1) API Username
- (2) API Password
- (3) API Signature

Can you please advise from where I can get this information please?

Comment: From paypal site.by creating an account at https://www.paypal.com/   From developers perspective try sandbox https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: Do you know where from the paypal website? I have created a merchant account and have been searching for the last 1 hour but cannot find it anywhere :(

Comment: Pasted in an answer check that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments

Login your account and find details as shown in the post http://www.putler.com/support/faq/how-to-get-paypal-api-username-password-and-signature-information/

Comment: @GordonBanks Good to hear it solved your problem....best thing to google first..search with diff keywords..look for the documentation if provided and then best place Stackoverflow :)